# Android: List of CardView

Tags: android, android-cardview

How can I create a list of CardView(s) like the one in the photo? Do I need a RecyclerView or not?

[image: CardView]

Comment: You can use a ListView or the new RecyclerView or even a simple ScrollView with a LinearLayout

Answer (score 3):

if you want it to look excactly like it is in the uploaded image then you would need either a listview and an adapter with a cardview layout or a recyclerview and a cardview layout, it is basically the cardview that gives the items that good elevated feeling otherwis the rest is the same, but i suggest you use a recyclerview since google is replacing the traditional listview with all `recycler`, here is a great tutorial you can use http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465